# div code css causing gray space on page

Tags: html, css, iframe

So I created a page with basically three main div's. The first div (.test_page - div #1) at the top of the page is a picture. The second div (.iframe_page - div #2) is an iframe of another site. The third div (.footer_coverup - div #3) is another picture.

Basically I wanted the top div (div #1) to cover up the header of the iframed site (div #2). I wanted the bottom div (div #3) to cover up the footer of the iframed site (div #2).

My style.css coding is:

```
.test_page {
  top: -60px;
  z-index: 9998;
}

.iframe_page {
  top: -230px;
}

.footer_coverup {
  padding-top: 250px;
  padding-bottom: 250px;
  width: 1577px;
  visibility: visible;
  background-image: url(/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/119.png);
  position: absolute;
  background-position: 50% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  top: -285px;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

However, there is now a gigantic gray space at the bottom of the page because I moved div #2 up and div #3 up using the code `top: -230px` for div #2 and `top: -285px` for div #3, as you can see in the code above.

Does anybody know how to move a div up and have the footer follow, instead of there being a big gray space at the bottom of the page??

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you post a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/) please?

Comment: Thanks for replying, Abhi. I'm not that tech savvy to use FIDDLE. I just want to know if I can use alternate coding to move div's upward without creating blank space at the bottom of the page.

Comment: The purpose of FIDDLE is to make your question clear to others. With the code above, it's difficult to foresee what actually is the problem. Fiddle helps getting a basic HTML, CSS and JS view of what you are trying.

Comment: It's hard to guess without seeing the problem but using negative margin-top might be your thing here.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than position the element using top.
Use the position relative property.

Also if you want the image till end of page,
Check background property: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-repeat.asp

Hope it helps.
Thanks !!!